# Lightbox - Galeria de imagens

Tags: html5, imagem, lightbox

Galera, muito boa noite

Estou apanhando para fazer uma galeria de fotos bem simples. Por exemplo, estou usando como base o link do site http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ para criar uma "Single image lightbox".

Copiei todo o código para uma página nova e o efeito não rodou! Estou usando o Safari como navegador. Para que o Lightbox funcione, é necessário instalar algo no localhost?

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
 type: 'image',
 closeOnContentClick: true,
 mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
 image: {
  verticalFit: true
 }
 
});

$('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
 type: 'image',
 closeOnContentClick: true,
 image: {
  verticalFit: false
 }
});

$('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
 type: 'image',
 closeOnContentClick: true,
 closeBtnInside: false,
 fixedContentPos: true,
 mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
 image: {
  verticalFit: true
 },
 zoom: {
  enabled: true,
  duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
 }
});

});
</script>

<a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_b.jpg" title="Caption. Can be aligned to any side and contain any HTML.">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a>
<a class="image-popup-fit-width" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_b.jpg" title="This image fits only horizontally.">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a>
<a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg">
<img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" width="107" height="75">
</a>

<style>
/* padding-bottom and top for image */
.mfp-no-margins img.mfp-img {
padding: 0;
}
/* position of shadow behind the image */
.mfp-no-margins .mfp-figure:after {
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
/* padding for main container */
.mfp-no-margins .mfp-container {
padding: 0;
}


/* 

for zoom animation 
uncomment this part if you haven't added this code anywhere else

*/


.mfp-with-zoom .mfp-container,
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-bg {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready .mfp-container {
 opacity: 1;
}
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing .mfp-container, 
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
opacity: 0;
}

</style>
```

O que há de errado afinal?

Obrigado

Comment: linkou todas bibliotecas necessárias para a execução do mesmo exemplo minimalista?

Answer (score 2):

O exemplo dessa pagina que você citou tem a dependência de 2 bibliotecas que você deve linkar/chamar na sua pagina para que funcione direitinho, `jquery` e `magnific-popup`, detalhe adicional, deve chamar primeiramente a biblioteca do `jquery` para que as funções criadas pelo `magnific-popup` que utilizam recursos do `jquery` sejam reconhecidas corretamente.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<script>
  
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
 type: 'image',
 closeOnContentClick: true,
 mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
 image: {
  verticalFit: true
 }
 
});

$('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
 type: 'image',
 closeOnContentClick: true,
 image: {
  verticalFit: false
 }
});

$('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
 type: 'image',
 closeOnContentClick: true,
 closeBtnInside: false,
 fixedContentPos: true,
 mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
 image: {
  verticalFit: true
 },
 zoom: {
  enabled: true,
  duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
 }
});

});
</script>

<a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_b.jpg" title="Caption. Can be aligned to any side and contain any HTML.">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a>
<a class="image-popup-fit-width" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_b.jpg" title="This image fits only horizontally.">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a>
<a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg">
<img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" width="107" height="75">
</a>

<style>
/* padding-bottom and top for image */
.mfp-no-margins img.mfp-img {
padding: 0;
}
/* position of shadow behind the image */
.mfp-no-margins .mfp-figure:after {
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
/* padding for main container */
.mfp-no-margins .mfp-container {
padding: 0;
}


/* 

for zoom animation 
uncomment this part if you haven't added this code anywhere else

*/


.mfp-with-zoom .mfp-container,
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-bg {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready .mfp-container {
 opacity: 1;
}
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing .mfp-container, 
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
opacity: 0;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Está com um erro ai...

Comment: Erro de CORS, apos o sopt passar a usar SSL o conteúdo desse site que não usa SSL foi bloqueado :)